# Is there any way to programaticallly save Excel cell to local files that could be load just like "copy and paste" with VSTO?

Tags: c#, excel, vba, vsto, office-addins

I've been working with Excel VSTO Add-in these days, and what I need is to load some templates from the database, and fill them in the Excel cells.

The thing is I can only store the data in plain text, the style and format would be missing if I try to copy and paste a target cell and store it somewhere in the notepads (or other editors).

Is there any way to save the cell data with styles to some binary local file (or others), and when I need it sometime, I could load and fill it to a targeted cell, like I have just copied it from some cells else.

Thanks!

PS: the text might have different styles so the storage of cell's formats might not work,

I've attached an example here:

[image: Example]

Comment: You can use excel VBA to copy both the content and the formatting settings of a cell/range as an object to a file, which could be then post-processed

Comment: @luizbarcelos ok thanks, I'll have a try, but is there any way to work it out with VSTO and C#?

Comment: imho, (this is a path worth digging..) ->  find/do a successful VBA code as proposed by @luizbarcelos , then load it via (1) 'triggered' by a button (easy to copy/apply to other file) (2) auto run at each file open (2) code in other language/tool ( C# , batch, powershell, or vbs) to 'call' the successful copy-with-format-code.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it with

> Range.Value[XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet]

It stores the cell as XML, with all the styles I need.